# Put cursor to the end of input search field

Tags: javascript

I have the search form with specific Java what put the cursor in the beginning of search form as show on code below

```
<form name="myform">
<div class="well form-search">
<input type="text" class="input-large" name="query" id="suggest" autocomplete="off"
value="&nbsp;<?=isset($_GET['query'])?  htmlentities($_GET['query']):''?>"> 
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="send" name="send" value="Submit">
<button type="reset" class="btn " accesskey="r" value="Reset">Reset</button>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
document.forms['myform'].elements['query'].focus();
</script>
```

**How to put the cursor to the end of text input values ?**

I already tried

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
document.forms['myform'].elements['query'].focus().input.setSelectionRange(1000,1000);
</script>
```

I guess something is wrong with my syntax, Thanks for a hint !

Comment: Java = JavaScript if, and only if, Ham = Hamster.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I always got told car = carpet

Comment: @scragar I like mine better, because it results in things like "hamster sandwiches" :p

Answer (score 4):

You appear to be trying to chain methods. This is a prominent feature of jQuery, but in vanilla JavaScript there isn't much chaining outside of DOM methods.

You'd want something like:

```
var elm = document.forms['myform'].elements['query'];
elm.focus();
elm.setSelectionRange(elm.value.length,elm.value.length);
```